# QGIS Grass-plugin output does not match the CRS of input files nor project CRS

Tags: qgis, qgis-grass-plugin

My project CRS and raster layer are EPSG:31467. However, when I use for example `r.to.vect` to create a polygon from the raster, the created vector layer has an unknown CRS and is a little bit off (does not match the source raster). When I manually set the CRS to EPSG:31467 the vector layer fits the source raster. But, when in a next step I create a line vector from the polygon using `v.to.lines` it happens again - although the input vector is EPSG:31467 the resulting line vector layer has an unknown CRS and is off.

Where is the problem? Can it be that the original raster file is actually not EPSG:31467? Because when I load it, the CRS is also unknown at first. I have just been told that it should be EPSG:31467 and therefore set it manually.

I am running QGIS 3.12.0.